# How to communicate with a command shell (like ipython or gdb) programaticaly

Tags: python, linux, shell, command, fifo

Is there a way to send input to a command shell without actually entering any keystroke ?

When launching gdb or ipython, the programs waits for user keyboard input. I was wondering if there is a way to communicate to those shells without entering any keystroke?

Maybe the command could be send to the shells through a fifo, and the answer from the shell redirected to a file or a fifo ?

Or use python subprocess Popen to create a wrapper around the shell?

The goal is to work with any kind of command shell.

Comment: I can't find a decent intro, but you definitely want `Tcl/Expect`.

Comment: Maybe this... https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html